# How to Select multivalues from list where list has only key value pair to fetch data

Tags: c#

clsPrimDataCollection = Dictionary <string,classPrimData>

`classPrimData.name|classPrimData.Age` is my key to hold classPrimData data i.e.

clsPrimDataCollection [`classPrimData.name|classPrimData.Age`,classPrimData ]

I need to fetch  records from  clsPrimDataCollection  where `classPrimData.city = 'XYZ'`

It's a legacy code so i could not change/alter any structre or  dictionaries in this case..

I tried with `List<classPrimData> clsPrimDataCollection.Select` or where but all i am getting is to select Key or value in the property.

Comment: Could you please provide full class definitions? Can you also provide sample input data in C# format and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Linq query to filter the values:

```
clsPrimDataCollection.Values.Where(x => x.city == "XYZ");
```

Please note that in this case, the efficient access by key that the dictionary provides, cannot be used. All values in the dictionary are searched for matching items.